# How to pass data with HttpPost

Tags: android, http, iis, post, httpclient

How do I pass data using an http post from an Android app using Java to a php file on a IIS server?

Comment: This is more of a Java and HTTP question than an Android question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/36/index.html and http://w3mentor.com/learn/java/android-development/android-http-services/performa-a-http-post-request-with-the-httpclient-in-android/ as examples.

Answer (score 2):

By this way you can pass data with HTTP POST and retrieve result

```
public class MyHttpPostProjectActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private EditText usernameEditText;
private EditText passwordEditText;
private Button sendPostReqButton;
private Button clearButton;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    usernameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_username_editText);
    passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password_editText);

    sendPostReqButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_sendPostReq_button);
    sendPostReqButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    clearButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_clear_button);
    clearButton.setOnClickListener(this);        
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v.getId() == R.id.login_clear_button){
        usernameEditText.setText("");
        passwordEditText.setText("");
        passwordEditText.setCursorVisible(false);
        passwordEditText.setFocusable(false);
        usernameEditText.setCursorVisible(true);
        passwordEditText.setFocusable(true);
    }else if(v.getId() == R.id.login_sendPostReq_button){
        String givenUsername = usernameEditText.getEditableText().toString();
        String givenPassword = passwordEditText.getEditableText().toString();

        System.out.println("Given username :" + givenUsername + " Given password :" + givenPassword);

        sendPostRequest(givenUsername, givenPassword);
    }   
}

private void sendPostRequest(String givenUsername, String givenPassword) {

    class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String paramUsername = params[0];
            String paramPassword = params[1];

            System.out.println("*** doInBackground ** paramUsername " + paramUsername + " paramPassword :" + paramPassword);

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // In a POST request, we don't pass the values in the URL.
            //Therefore we use only the web page URL as the parameter of the HttpPost argument
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.nirmana.lk/hec/android/postLogin.php");

            // Because we are not passing values over the URL, we should have a mechanism to pass the values that can be
            //uniquely separate by the other end.
            //To achieve that we use BasicNameValuePair             
            //Things we need to pass with the POST request
            BasicNameValuePair usernameBasicNameValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("paramUsername", paramUsername);
            BasicNameValuePair passwordBasicNameValuePAir = new BasicNameValuePair("paramPassword", paramPassword);

            // We add the content that we want to pass with the POST request to as name-value pairs
            //Now we put those sending details to an ArrayList with type safe of NameValuePair
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairList.add(usernameBasicNameValuePair);
            nameValuePairList.add(passwordBasicNameValuePAir);

            try {
                // UrlEncodedFormEntity is an entity composed of a list of url-encoded pairs. 
                //This is typically useful while sending an HTTP POST request. 
                UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairList);

                // setEntity() hands the entity (here it is urlEncodedFormEntity) to the request.
                httpPost.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);

                try {
                    // HttpResponse is an interface just like HttpPost.
                    //Therefore we can't initialize them
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    // According to the JAVA API, InputStream constructor do nothing. 
                    //So we can't initialize InputStream although it is not an interface
                    InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

                    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    String bufferedStrChunk = null;

                    while((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                        stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
                    }

                    return stringBuilder.toString();

                } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
                    System.out.println("First Exception caz of HttpResponese :" + cpe);
                    cpe.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    System.out.println("Second Exception caz of HttpResponse :" + ioe);
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                System.out.println("An Exception given because of UrlEncodedFormEntity argument :" + uee);
                uee.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(result.equals("working")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HTTP POST is working...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid POST req...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }           
    }

    SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
    sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(givenUsername, givenPassword);     
}
```

}